# Ruby on Rails, ActiveRecord query (boss can see the gratitudes that his employees have received.)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following relation between tables:

[image: tables]

In the Users table, employees are assigned a "manager_id" (boss). In the Gratitudes table,
user_id is the "current_user" and send_to user_id is the user to whom the "current_user" will send a Gratitude. I want to have a list where the manager_id(if is logged "current_user") can see the gratitudes that his employees have received.

Example:

[image: example]

I have some queries in SQL, but since I work in Ruby on Rails, I like having queries with ActiveRecord:

i have this:

```
@employees_gratitudes = Gratitude.joins(:user).where("users.manager_id = 'current_user'").all
```

SQL:

```
SELECT gratitudes.user_id as de ,  gratitudes.send_to_user_id as para, gratitudes.id ,gratitudes.subject as mensaje, gratitudes.message FROM gratitudes
inner join users on gratitudes.user_id = users.manager_id
where gratitudes.user_id = 2
```

but I have not succeeded in getting the query right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, not sure if this will work or not. 
I'd suggest changing the following in the `gratitudes` table.

- `send_to_user_id` to `receiver_id`
- `user_id` to `sender_id`

Assuming that you now have the following association in the `Gratitude` Model

- `belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'`

ActiveRecord Query:

`Gratitide.joins(:receiver).where(users: { manager: current_user })`

Comment: bro! you're awesome! Thanks!, you save me. I only change the joins(:user) by joins(:send_to_user). and it works!